# Remove rows if the swap also exist in the data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to remove those rows if the swap also exists in the data frame.

For example, if I have a data frame:

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 4
4 2
2 1
```

Then the row (1,2), (2,4) will be removed because (2,1) and (4,2) are also in the df.
Is there any fast and neat way to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Can same row be repeated twice? For eg - (1, 2) and (1, 2) ?

Comment: no, if (1, 2) is in the list then (2,1) can not be in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can row-wise sort the columns and then select only the unique ones :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
 mutate(col1 = pmin(V1, V2), 
        col2 = pmax(V1, V2)) %>%
 distinct(col1, col2)

#  col1 col2
#1    1    2
#2    1    3
#3    1    4
#4    2    4
```

---

Using base R :

```
df1 <- transform(df, col1 = pmin(V1, V2), col2 = pmax(V1, V2))
df[!duplicated(df1[3:4]), ]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L), V2 = c(2L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: I like the dplyr solution, it is pretty fast! Thank you!

Comment: No, wait. Do you want to remove both the original and the swap? meaning (1, 2) and (2, 1) ? My answer only removes (2, 1).

Comment: In case if you want to remove both, you can use `df[!(duplicated(df1[3:4]) | duplicated(df1[3:4], fromLast = TRUE)), ]`

Comment: No I mean remain either (1,2) or (2,1) so I think your answer meets my need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another, `base R`, solution is by using `rowSums`and `duplicated`:

```
df[!duplicated(rowSums(df)),]
  V1 V2
1  1  2
2  1  3
3  1  4
4  2  4
```